# Bukkit won't load the plugin: name is not defined

Tags: java, bukkit

Here's my code:

```
package me.chimericalhobo.BlockChanger;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class BlockChanger extends JavaPlugin
{

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
private final BlockChangerListener blockListener = new BlockChangerListener(this);
public final ArrayList<Player> BlockChangerUsers = new ArrayList<Player>();

@Override
public void onEnable()
{
    log.info("[BlockChanger] has been enabled!");
    PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
    pm.registerEvents(this.blockListener, this);
}

@Override
public void onDisable()
{
    log.info("[BlockChanger] has been disabled!");
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args)
{
    if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("BlockChanger"))
        toggleBlockChanger(sender);

    return true;

}

private void toggleBlockChanger(CommandSender sender)
{
    if(!enabled((Player) sender)){
        BlockChangerUsers.add((Player) sender);
        ((Player) sender).sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "BlockChanger has been enabled!");

    }
    else
    {
        BlockChangerUsers.remove((Player) sender);
        ((Player) sender).sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "BlockChanger has been disabled!");
    }

}

public boolean enabled(Player player)
{
    return BlockChangerUsers.contains(player);
}

}
```

Every time I try to load it the command prompt says:

```
15:53:08 [SEVERE] Could not load 'plugins\BlockChanger.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: name is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

In the *plugin.yml* add this:

```
name: (Plugin Name)
main: (Package.name.name(or whatever).(MainClass Ex: .Main)) Ex: me.name.plugin.Main
version: (Version number)
```

Optionally you can add things such as `author: (author name)`.

Look at http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_YAML for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Check your *plugin.yml*.
Are you sure you have set a `name: <plugin name>` field in it?

Answer (score 2):

A plugin needs to consist of a name.

In the *plugin.yml* you will see a field that says:

```
name:
```

Here you must insert a name of your plugin.

A complete example of a *plugin.yml* looks like this:

```
name: Velocity Jump
main: com.weebly.foxgenesis.Main
version: 1.0

commands:
   vjump:
      description: make a player velocity jump to you
      usage: /vjump <player> [toPlayer] [time]
      default: op
```

For more info please click this link: http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_YAML